# Hide push notification if it contains specific elements

Tags: java, android, react-native, onesignal

I won't show a received push notification from appearing top notifications menu my notification if it has for example key `update`. For now if I get notification with this key, all notifications are in the notification bar. I want to not present this notifications for user.

I'm using `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` for handle notifications like below:

```
public class PusherReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
    private boolean isAppOnForeground(Context context) {
        ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> appProcesses = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
        if (appProcesses == null) 
            return false;

        final String packageName = context.getPackageName();
        for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo appProcess : appProcesses) {
            if (appProcess.importance == ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND && appProcess.processName.equals(packageName)) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i("SimpleWakefulReceiver", "Starting service @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
        if (!isAppOnForeground((context))) {
            String pushNotificationBody = intent.getStringExtra("alert");

            try {
                JSONObject notificationData = new JSONObject(pushNotificationBody);

                // This is the Intent to deliver to our service.
                Intent service = new Intent(context, BackgroundService.class);
                // Put here your data from the json as extra in in the intent
                service.putExtra("notification", pushNotificationBody);

                Log.i("PUSH_NOTIFICATION_JSON", "RECEIVED JSON " + notificationData);

                // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
                if (!notificationData.has("update")) {
                    startWakefulService(context, service);
                } else {
                    // Do nothing
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

I changed project a little and with `Onesignal` and his `NotificationExtenderService`, I did something like below:

```
public class NotificationNotDisplayingExtender extends NotificationExtenderService {
    @Override
    protected boolean onNotificationProcessing(OSNotificationReceivedResult receivedResult) {
        String notification = receivedResult.toString();
        String notificationBody = receivedResult.payload.body;
        JSONObject notificationBodyJSON = null;
        try {
            notificationBodyJSON = new JSONObject(notificationBody);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        JSONObject pushNotificationData = notificationBodyJSON;
        boolean hidden = false;

        if (pushNotificationData.has("update")) {
            Log.i("NOTIFICATION MANAGER", "PREVENT DISPLAY NOTIFICATION");

            hidden = true;
        }


        // Return true to stop the notification from displaying.
        return hidden;
    }
}
```

And it prevent displaying notifications with update key, but now I don't receive it in my PusherReceiver to start my service. Is there easy way to send data from my `NotificationNotDisplayingExtender` receivedResult to my `PusherReceiver`?

For now it looks like my PusherReceiver don't fire his `onReceive` method.

Many thanks for help in advance.

Comment: You should notice this is deprecated since api 26: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver.html

Comment: @user1209216 Yep, I know and for newer api I will do update for this, but now I need to find a solution for notifications. :/

Comment: if I  understand your question correctly, you just have to stop calling the NotificationManager to stop showing the notification. The notification are only shown when you build them and call notify. Just use your service to process the data without building a notification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you `notify` the `NotificationManager` to show a notification, you provide an ID to be used for the notification to edit or cancel that notification later on. If you show a notification by `manager.notify(notificationId, notification)`, you can cancel it with `manager.cancel(notificationId)`.

If you want to remove all the notifications, you can use `NotificationManager.cancelAll()`.

Comment: Thanks for advice Adib. Canceling notifications works, but it looks weird when user get's notification with vibration, and it's canceled just after receive. I updated my question and I hope only one problem left.

Comment: From what I understand you fixed the previous issue, now you have a `BroadcastReceiver` that does not get called and you want to cal it? If that is the case you can call your broad cast receiver like this:
```Intent intent = new Intent("my.action.string"); context.sendBroadcast(intent);```. you need to change the intent action according to your desired receiver.

Comment: I did it by sending broadcast regarding your advice if notification has update key in `NotificationNotDisplayingExtender` I created an intent and did something like below and it works: `Intent intent = new Intent();` I set action the same like I set in manifest for my intent `intent.setAction("MY_NOTIFICATION");` and after that I added data to my intent and send broadcast `intent.putExtra("data", notificationBody);
            sendBroadcast(intent);` Thanks, it works! :)

Comment: @Robson this is way to do so, first you are creating the notification and then removing that

Answer (score 2):

There are two types of payload.
1. Data
2. Notification

https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options

Use only data payload. Then you always get the call in FirebaseMessagingService onMessageRececived Method

Comment: Just let me know, if face any issue while implementation

Answer (score 1):

The thing is basically we have two type of notifications.

One which can be called **Notification Type**, is that the push has a `notification` object in sent/received bundle, in which you have to handle it when your app is in foreground and the notification is received. In this case, if your app is in foreground, then you can handle it and do whatever you like which is not showing a notification. But if the app is in background, a notification will automatically create by google and it takes predefined `title` and `message` objects within the received push bundle to make the notification.

Second type which can be called **Data Type**, do not have any `notification` object in the sent/received bundle. In this scenario, your app is in foreground or background, you should handle everything. So, if you put your data in `data` object of your push notification message, everything will be in your hands.

So, in short, just put your data in `data` object of your notification and implement your desired logic.

Answer (score 1):

I do not see the JSON data you are referring to. However, I suppose the `update` key in your JSON is containing `null`. In your code you are checking if the JSON data has the key `update` in it. This function will always return true if the key exists in the JSON body. You might have the field with `null` value which is indicating that you are not supposed to show the notification in the system tray.

In that case, you might consider using `isNull` function. It returns true if this object has no mapping for `update` or if it has a mapping whose value is `null`.

```
// Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
if (!notificationData.isNull("update")) {
    startWakefulService(context, service);
} else {
    // Do nothing
}
```

And yes, please use the `data` payload from the notification that you get.

Comment: Hmm, it prevent running wakeful service, but notifications are still displayed. Important thing is that this problem exists only if app is on background/closed.